# Excel 2010 E-mail VBA send entire workbook

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I have been looking for a VBA that can send the entire workbook.

I found this

```
    Sub Mail()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next

    With OutMail
        .To = "mymail@domain.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = Range("A1").Value
        .body = ""
        .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        .send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

But when opening the sent mail, the workbook is all empty. So I have to save the workbook before using VBA.

Is there a workaround for this, so it just work as normal File -> Save and send -> Send as attachment?

Comment: No, it has to be saved first so that it has a filename to be attached.

Comment: You could always just save it as a temp file, attach the temp file, then delete it...

Comment: Alright. So there is no fix for this? The option of saving temporary file, makes the process slower than just going for the file -> save and attach option.

Comment: Unless someone else knows of a way... the question remains open to other answers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I'm assuming you don't want to save it so work with [ [Application.Dialogs MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.dialogs)  ]*

*Example 1*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub example()
    Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSendMail).Show _
                arg1:="mymail@domain.com", _
                arg2:=Range("A1").Value
End Sub
```

---

*Example 2 [ [Workbook.SendMail MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.sendmail) ] Sends the workbook using installed mail system*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub example()
ActiveWorkbook.SendMail _
     Recipients:=Array("mymail@domain.com", "mymail@domain.com"), _
        Subject:=Range("A1").Value
End Sub
```

---

*Or save your workbook before sending.*

*Example*

> ```
>   ActiveWorkbook.Save
>  .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
>  .send
> ```